# Building flavors and defaultConfig using play button in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have created the following gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        applicationId 'com.kibo.mobi.app'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1{
            applicationId 'com.kibo.mobi.flavor1'
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 20
        }
        flavor2{
            applicationId 'com.kibo.mobi.flavor2'
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 20
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        flavor1{
            manifest.srcFile 'flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/assets']

        }

        flavor2{
            manifest.srcFile 'flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/assets']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':AppSDK')
}
```

Pressing the `Play/Run` button in `Android Studio` results in building, compiling and installing the "flavor1" version on the connected device.

How can I manually configure what version will be installed? When the default version (not a flavor - but the "main" folder) is also a version I need to install sometimes. So basically there are 3 version here that I need to have the ability to install each one of them as requested.

Answer (score 2):

The "Build Variants" tool window (**View** menu > **Tool windows** > **Build variants**) lets you select which flavor + build type combination will be built and run by default.